# Why ASP.NET Web Configuration Tool was excluded from Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I couldn't find any satisfactory answer for this question.

1. Does someone know the reason?
2. What kind of thing does Microsoft offer instead of it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about speculating about a software company's motivations.

Comment: Have a look at [this MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/08/19/asp-net-web-configuration-tool-missing-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was removed because the Web Configuration Tool worked only with ASP.NET Membership, while Visual Studio 2013 no longer supports that and uses ASP.NET Identity, which is not compatible with the Web Configuration Tool.

While it's possible to still use the old membership library, it's more or less deprecated.

Could they have rewritten it for ASP.NET Identity?  Probably, but they didn't... or provide a replacement, which they didn't either.

One of the major problems was that the Web Configuration Tool only allowed configuration via Web.config, which Microsoft does not support for ASP.NET MVC.  They also shouldn't support it for Webforms, but unfortunately they don't have much of a choice since they don't have any other mechanism for Webforms right now.

Microsoft doesn't offer any other configuration tool for web security out of the box.